# How can I make the appendix one column to fit my very long equations? And also keep equations from running off the page?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, columns

The rest of the document is two columns, just the appendix needs to be one column to fit the equations. 
Here is the code, any help greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{arcCosh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsech}{arcsech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsch}{arccsch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccoth}{arccoth}

\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Appendix}
\label{appendix}

\be
 H_{z} = -\frac{M}{48 \pi b_{zN}^{2}} 
  \left(
12dw \sqrt{d^{2} + w^{2}} 
- 16dw \sqrt{4 b_{zN}^{2} + d^{2} + w^{2}}
+ 4dw \sqrt{16  b_{zN}^{2} + d^{2} + w^{2}} 
- 12w^{3}  \arccoth\left({\frac{d}{d^{2}+w^{2}}} \right)
+ 16w^{3} \arccoth \left({\frac{d}{4b_{zN}^{2}+d^{2}+w^{2}}} \right)...
 \right)
\ee

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `epsfig` package is outdated for a long time and `\be` and `ee` is not a really good idea. Try `split` or `multline` instead of `equation`

Comment: you are loading amsmath which defines many multi-line displays, do not use `equation` use `multline` or `gather` or `align` depending on your requirements. Also why capital C in arcCosh ??

Comment: I’m not sure to understand what you mean: are you asking how to start one-column mode in a two-column document?  If so, say `\onecolumn` before `\section*{Appendix}`.  It would be better to also load the _geometry_ package and define a new page geometry at that point, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is, in more detail, what I mean when I speak of using the *geometry* package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Article}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Bar}
\lipsum[5-8]

\section{Baz}
\lipsum[9-16]

\newgeometry{onecolumn,textwidth=345pt} % adjust value if needed

\section{This is in one-column mode}
\lipsum[17-20]

\end{document}
```

In the `\newgeometry` command, you can also set the `hmarginratio`, if you wish to; but in most cases the default value (which automatically conforms to the `oneside`/`twoside` setting) will do.